# DataSource C# - Problema ao ler vários dados

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho um código, onde ele abre o navegador e trabalha dentro de uma determinada página.
Nessa página, tenho alguns campos, onde eu busco informações de uma planilha em excel (xlsx). Nessa mesma página, tem um campo CEP onde tem uma lupa também (que serve para buscar mais CEP), porém, ao clicar nessa lupa, ele fecha meu navegador e abre o outro navegador (ou seja, pegando o próximo dado da planilha em excel).

Como eu consigo que ele continue trabalhando dentro dessa página, sem que ele tenha que sair e ir buscar outro dado na minha planilha em excel?

```
[CodedUITest]
public class TesteCEP: loginSistema
{
    //Test case nº...

    [TestMethod]
    [DeploymentItem("Teste\\ArquivoExcel.xlsx")]
    [DataSource("ExcelCEP")]
    [DeploymentItem("Teste\\chromedriver.exe")]
    public void testarCEP()
    {
        LogarNoSistema();

        //Inicio Código
        //Declaração de variáveis
        var cep = this.TestContext.DataRow["CEP"].ToString();
        ...  
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("campo_CEP")).SendKeys(CEP);
        WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("lupa_CEP")).SendKeys(click);
       }
    }
```

Isso é uma demonstração, tentando explicar um pouco melhor do que eu estou tentando fazer.

Comment: Web Forms ?....

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar essas duas linhas dentro de um `for each` para cada `DataRow`:

```
WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("campo_CEP")).SendKeys(CEP);
WebDriver.FindElement(By.Id("lupa_CEP")).SendKeys(click);
```